# How to build multilib mingw-w64 gcc toolchain

Tags: gcc, build, mingw-w64

I used to use MSVC a lot, and now I want to try out new C++17 features, so I decided to use mingw-w64 toolchian.

Btw I'm new to building things from source

I also want the ability to compile both 32 bit and 64 bit application (multilib).

I had mingw-w64 headers installed, then I tried to bootstrap GCC 7.1.0 in MSYS2.
I configured it by this command

```
../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --prefix=/c/tmp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/tmp/gcc/dest --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
```

The process completed without an error, however the compiler isn't usable.

I tried to compile a file `a.cpp` by

```
g++ -o a.exe a.cpp
```

Unfortunately, a message box with title cc1plus appeared saying `The code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found. 
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.`

That suggested that I should have libgcc, but how can I get it?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use two separate toolchains for 32 and 64-bit. It will save you a world of pain in both getting the toolchains built and getting things built with the toolchains. Last time I tried, DLLs were getting overwritten preventing any useful result. It's highly likely you'll need some GCC build system patches for this to work at all. So just don't, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just wondering if I can build multilib toolchain myself. And so that's the reason that they no longer provided multilib toolchain at sourceforge?

Comment: I world guess so. There are just too many difficulties building an maintaining these for GCC. Clang is another stort, and I think it would be somewhat simpler to do a multi target setup there.